# Generate Google Cloud Endpoints - Android studio

Tags: google-app-engine, android-studio, google-cloud-endpoints

I've been trying to add a Google Cloud Backend to my android application using Android Studio. I've been following along with this I/O talk: http://youtu.be/lmv1dTnhLH4?t=37m2s and I realise that things have changed a bit from back then. In the video, he generates an endpoint be right clicking on a java file like the one below then selecting 'Generate Cloud Endpoint' which produces an endpoint java class he can then use in his app. I'm using Android Studio v0.5.6 and that option doesn't seem to be there any more. It seems all of the Android studio documentation relating to App Engine integration I've found on the internet hasn't been updated. Could anyone point me in the right direction to get this set up using the latest versions of Android Studio.

To add the backend I selected Tools > Google Cloud Tools > Add App Engine Backend:

[image: Steps taken to add backend module]

Class I am trying to create an endpoint for:

[image]

User class:

```
package com.test.lol;

import com.googlecode.objectify.annotation.Entity;
import com.googlecode.objectify.annotation.Id;

import java.util.Date;

@Entity
public class User {

    @Id
    private String mID;
    private String mFirstName;
    private String mLastName;
    private String mEmail;
    private String mBirthday;
    private Date mLastSeen;

    public String getID() {
        return mID;
    }

    public void setID(String ID) {
        this.mID = ID;
    }

    public String getFirstName() {
        return mFirstName;
    }

    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        mFirstName = firstName;
    }

    public String getLastName() {
        return mLastName;
    }

    public void setLastName(String lastName) {
        mLastName = lastName;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return mEmail;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        mEmail = email;
    }

    public String getBirthday() {
        return mBirthday;
    }

    public void setBirthday(String birthday) {
        mBirthday = birthday;
    }

    public Date getLastSeen() {
        return mLastSeen;
    }

    public void setLastSeen(Date lastSeen) {
        mLastSeen = lastSeen;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Google have acknowledged this feature is missing and are working to implement it.

**Source:** https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=68223

**Edit:** This feature has been implemented in the beta version of Android Studio

In the mean time, I:

- Was able to use the [Google Endpoint documentation](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/endpoints/) to figure out
  which annotations to use for the Endpoint API.
- Checked out the [Objectify Documentation](https://code.google.com/p/objectify-appengine/wiki/Introduction) to figure out which
  annotations to use for `Entities` and Datastore persistance.
- Uploaded my code to app engine using the terminal command: `gradlew appengineUpdateAll`
- Installed the android client libraries to my local Maven repository using the terminal command: `gradlew appengineEndpointsInstallClientLibs`
- Followed [this tutorial](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/endpoints/consume_android) on how to add the google API client to my Gradle project.
- Added the local Maven repo to my projects build.gradle file and the client library as a dependency in my app's build.gradle
- Used the Endpoint in my app.
- Double fist pumped the air with great elation and proclaimed "I am the master commander!"

Comment: I just created the Endpoints using the Eclipse plugin but am having trouble with the creation of the client library in AS (I tried creating them in Eclipse to copy over but wasn't sure what to copy or where to put it).  Could you explain exactly how you did it?

Comment: Disregard, I noticed you were using Objectify, not JDO/JPA

Comment: All steps described here are right. Here you can find a complete tutorial of thist steps based on Android Studio 0.8.6. [http://devroyal.de/app-engine-based-java-endpoints-android-studio/](http://devroyal.de/app-engine-based-java-endpoints-android-studio/)

Answer (score 1):

Finally Google Cloud Backend has been added again in Android Studio 0.6.1:
http://android-developers.blogspot.it/2014/06/new-ways-to-connect-your-app-to-the-cloud-android-studio.html